# Deadlock in Oracle 3

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, deadlock

I have found following errors on Oracle.. 
I cant understand what is happening here. 
Cant understand which session is waiting for what.... 
Also is it about Raw level lock or something?

Can anyone please help me?

```
*** 2015-03-10 10:23:30.288
DEADLOCK DETECTED ( ORA-00060 )

[Transaction Deadlock]

The following deadlock is not an ORACLE error. It is a
deadlock due to user error in the design of an application
or from issuing incorrect ad-hoc SQL. The following
information may aid in determining the deadlock:

Deadlock graph:
                                             ---------Blocker(s)--------  ---------Waiter(s)---------
Resource Name          process session holds waits  process session holds waits
TX-001c0006-0000a440        94    2903     X            123    2284           X
TX-001d0011-0000fac7       123    2284     X             94    2903           X

session 2903: DID 0001-005E-00018DE5    session 2284: DID 0001-007B-0001863D 
session 2284: DID 0001-007B-0001863D    session 2903: DID 0001-005E-00018DE5 

Rows waited on:
    Session 2903: obj - rowid = 0001285E - AAASheAAIAABMBIAAV
    (dictionary objn - 75870, file - 8, block - 311368, slot - 21)
    Session 2284: obj - rowid = 0001285E - AAASheAAIAABL9/AAq
    (dictionary objn - 75870, file - 8, block - 311167, slot - 42)

----- Information for the OTHER waiting sessions -----
Session 2284:
    sid: 2284 ser: 207 audsid: 2893404 user: 87/ESS_ADMIN flags: 0x45
    pid: 123 O/S info: user: oracle, term: UNKNOWN, ospid: 3209
        image: oracle@pbifmsdb2
    client details:
        O/S info: user: root, term: unknown, ospid: 1234
        machine: pbifmsapp2 program: JDBC Thin Client
        application name: JDBC Thin Client, hash value=2546894660
    current SQL:
    UPDATE SEC_LOGIN_AUDIT SET LOGOUT_TIME= SYSDATE,LOGOUT_TYPE=:1 ,LST_UPDT_DT= SYSDATE WHERE  UPPER(USER_NAME) IN UPPER(:2 ) AND LOGOUT_TYPE IS NULL AND TRUNC(LOGIN_DATE_TIME) BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE)-1 AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) 

----- End of information for the OTHER waiting sessions -----

Information for THIS session:

----- Current SQL Statement for this session (sql_id=cm6x9vt91y3v3) -----
UPDATE SEC_LOGIN_AUDIT SET LOGOUT_TIME= SYSDATE,LOGOUT_TYPE=:1 ,LST_UPDT_DT= SYSDATE WHERE  UPPER(USER_NAME) IN UPPER(:2 ) AND LOGOUT_TYPE IS NULL AND TRUNC(LOGIN_DATE_TIME) BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE)-1 AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) 
===================================================
PROCESS STATE
-------------
Process global information:
         process: 0xc000001154e37f70, call: 0xc00000113a5ee668, xact: 0xc0000011489d4808, curses: 0xc0000011598a5760, usrses: 0xc0000011598a5760
    ----------------------------------------
    SO: 0xc000001154e37f70, type: 2, owner: 0x0000000000000000, flag: INIT/-/-/0x00 if: 0x3 c: 0x3
     proc=0xc000001154e37f70, name=process, file=ksu.h LINE:11459 ID:, pg=0
    (process) Oracle pid:94, ser:1, calls cur/top: 0xc00000113a5ee668/0xc00000113a5ee668
                        flags : (0x0) -
                        flags2: (0x0),  flags3: (0x0) 
                        intr error: 0, call error: 0, sess error: 0, txn error 0
                        intr queue: empty
    ksudlp FALSE at location: 0
    (post info) last post received: 134 0 2
                            last post received-location: ksl2.h LINE:2165 ID:kslpsr
                            last process to post me: c00000115cda7358 10 6
                            last post sent: 0 0 26
                            last post sent-location: ksa2.h LINE:282 ID:ksasnd
                            last process posted by me: c00000115cda7358 10 6
        (latch info) wait_event=0 bits=0
        Process Group: DEFAULT, pseudo proc: 0xc000001170f9b220
        O/S info: user: oracle, term: UNKNOWN, ospid: 9438 
        OSD pid info: Unix process pid: 9438, image: oracle@pbifmsdb2
Dump of memory from 0xC000001154DE40C8 to 0xC000001154DE42D0
C000001154DE40C0                   00000000 00000000          [........]
C000001154DE40D0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  [................]
    Repeat 31 times
        (FOB) flags=2066 fib=c000001173a56518 incno=0 pending i/o cnt=0
         fname=/iwdmsdata/PIWDMS/DATA/ess_data.dbf
         fno=8 lblksz=8192 fsiz=339200
        (FOB) flags=2066 fib=c000001173a55900 incno=0 pending i/o cnt=0
         fname=/iwdmsdata/PIWDMS/DATA/iwas_data.dbf
         fno=6 lblksz=8192 fsiz=3678848
        (FOB) flags=2050 fib=c000001173a58348 incno=0 pending i/o cnt=0
         fname=/iwdmsdata/PIWDMS/DATA/temp01.dbf
         fno=201 lblksz=8192 fsiz=4194176
        (FOB) flags=2050 fib=c000001173a56518 incno=0 pending i/o cnt=0
         fname=/iwdmsdata/PIWDMS/DATA/ess_data.dbf
         fno=8 lblksz=8192 fsiz=339200
        (FOB) flags=2050 fib=c000001173a546d0 incno=0 pending i/o cnt=0
         fname=/iwdmsdata/PIWDMS/DATA/undotbs01.dbf
         fno=3 lblksz=8192 fsiz=231040
        (FOB) flags=2050 fib=c000001173a55f00 incno=0 pending i/o cnt=0
         fname=/iwdmsdata/PIWDMS/DATA/iwas_index.dbf
         fno=7 lblksz=8192 fsiz=470400
        (FOB) flags=2050 fib=c000001173a55900 incno=0 pending i/o cnt=0
         fname=/iwdmsdata/PIWDMS/DATA/iwas_data.dbf
         fno=6 lblksz=8192 fsiz=3678848
        (FOB) flags=2050 fib=c000001173a53ab8 incno=0 pending i/o cnt=0
         fname=/iwdmsdata/PIWDMS/DATA/system01.dbf
         fno=1 lblksz=8192 fsiz=204800
        ----------------------------------------
        SO: 0xc0000011598a5760, type: 4, owner: 0xc000001154e37f70, flag: INIT/-/-/0x00 if: 0x3 c: 0x3
         proc=0xc000001154e37f70, name=session, file=ksu.h LINE:11467 ID:, pg=0
        (session) sid: 2903 ser: 7 trans: 0xc0000011489d4808, creator: 0xc000001154e37f70
                            flags: (0x45) USR/- flags_idl: (0x1) BSY/-/-/-/-/-
                            flags2: (0x40008) -/-
                            DID: , short-term DID: 
                            txn branch: 0xc00000114052f870
                            oct: 6, prv: 0, sql: 0xc00000116796d070, psql: 0xc0000011675cd1f0, user: 87/ESS_ADMIN
        ksuxds FALSE at location: 0
        service name: SYS$USERS
        client details:
            O/S info: user: root, term: unknown, ospid: 1234
            machine: pbifmsapp2 program: JDBC Thin Client
            application name: JDBC Thin Client, hash value=2546894660
        Current Wait Stack:
         0: waiting for 'enq: TX - row lock contention'
                name|mode=0x54580006, usn<<16 | slot=0x1d0011, sequence=0xfac7
                wait_id=471131 seq_num=12392 snap_id=1
                wait times: snap=3.004466 sec, exc=3.004466 sec, total=3.004466 sec
                wait times: max=1 min 0 sec, heur=3.004466 sec
                wait counts: calls=1 os=1
                in_wait=1 iflags=0x15a0
        There is at least one session blocking this session.
            Dumping 1 direct blocker(s):
                inst: 1, sid: 2284, ser: 207
            Dumping final blocker:
                inst: 1, sid: 2284, ser: 207
        Wait State:
            fixed_waits=0 flags=0x22 boundary=0x0000000000000000/-1
        Session Wait History:
                elapsed time of 1.625218 sec since current wait
         0: waited for 'SQL*Net message from client'
                driver id=0x74637000, #bytes=0x1, =0x0
                wait_id=471130 seq_num=12391 snap_id=1
                wait times: snap=0.000630 sec, exc=0.000630 sec, total=0.000630 sec
                wait times: max=infinite
                wait counts: calls=0 os=0
                occurred after 0.000003 sec of elapsed time
         1: waited for 'SQL*Net message to client'
                driver id=0x74637000, #bytes=0x1, =0x0
                wait_id=471129 seq_num=12390 snap_id=1
                wait times: snap=0.000000 sec, exc=0.000000 sec, total=0.000000 sec
                wait times: max=infinite
                wait counts: calls=0 os=0
                occurred after 0.000039 sec of elapsed time
         2: waited for 'SQL*Net message from client'
                driver id=0x74637000, #bytes=0x1, =0x0
                wait_id=471128 seq_num=12389 snap_id=1
                wait times: snap=0.002370 sec, exc=0.002370 sec, total=0.002370 sec
                wait times: max=infinite
                wait counts: calls=0 os=0
                occurred after 0.000001 sec of elapsed time
         3: waited for 'SQL*Net message to client'
                driver id=0x74637000, #bytes=0x1, =0x0
                wait_id=471127 seq_num=12388 snap_id=1
                wait times: snap=0.000001 sec, exc=0.000001 sec, total=0.000001 sec
                wait times: max=infinite
                wait counts: calls=0 os=0
                occurred after 0.000069 sec of elapsed time
         4: waited for 'SQL*Net message from client'
                driver id=0x74637000, #bytes=0x1, =0x0
                wait_id=471126 seq_num=12387 snap_id=1
                wait times: snap=0.000659 sec, exc=0.000659 sec, total=0.000659 sec
                wait times: max=infinite
                wait counts: calls=0 os=0
                occurred after 0.000004 sec of elapsed time
         5: waited for 'SQL*Net message to client'
                driver id=0x74637000, #bytes=0x1, =0x0
                wait_id=471125 seq_num=12386 snap_id=1
                wait times: snap=0.000001 sec, exc=0.000001 sec, total=0.000001 sec
                wait times: max=infinite
                wait counts: calls=0 os=0
                occurred after 0.001259 sec of elapsed time
         6: waited for 'SQL*Net message from client'
                driver id=0x74637000, #bytes=0x1, =0x0
                wait_id=471124 seq_num=12385 snap_id=1
                wait times: snap=0.000447 sec, exc=0.000447 sec, total=0.000447 sec
                wait times: max=infinite
                wait counts: calls=0 os=0
                occurred after 0.000036 sec of elapsed time
         7: waited for 'SQL*Net message to client'
                driver id=0x74637000, #bytes=0x1, =0x0
                wait_id=471123 seq_num=12384 snap_id=1
                wait times: snap=0.000006 sec, exc=0.000006 sec, total=0.000006 sec
                wait times: max=infinite
                wait counts: calls=0 os=0
                occurred after 1.741446 sec of elapsed time
         8: waited for 'SQL*Net message from client'
                driver id=0x74637000, #bytes=0x1, =0x0
                wait_id=471122 seq_num=12383 snap_id=1
                wait times: snap=0.001060 sec, exc=0.001060 sec, total=0.001060 sec
                wait times: max=infinite
                wait counts: calls=0 os=0
                occurred after 0.000002 sec of elapsed time
         9: waited for 'SQL*Net message to client'
                driver id=0x74637000, #bytes=0x1, =0x0
                wait_id=471121 seq_num=12382 snap_id=1
                wait times: snap=0.000001 sec, exc=0.000001 sec, total=0.000001 sec
                wait times: max=infinite
                wait counts: calls=0 os=0
                occurred after 0.000038 sec of elapsed time
        Sampled Session History of session 2903 serial 7
        ---------------------------------------------------
        The sampled session history is constructed by sampling
        the target session every 1 second. The sampling process
        captures at each sample if the session is in a non-idle wait,
        an idle wait, or not in a wait. If the session is in a
        non-idle wait then one interval is shown for all the samples
        the session was in the same non-idle wait. If the
        session is in an idle wait or not in a wait for
        consecutive samples then one interval is shown for all
        the consecutive samples. Though we display these consecutive
        samples  in a single interval the session may NOT be continuously
        idle or not in a wait (the sampling process does not know).

        The history is displayed in reverse chronological order.

        sample interval: 1 sec, max history 120 sec
        ---------------------------------------------------
            [3 samples,                                          10:23:27 - 10:23:29]
                waited for 'enq: TX - row lock contention', seq_num: 12392
                    p1: 'name|mode'=0x54580006
                    p2: 'usn<<16 | slot'=0x1d0011
                    p3: 'sequence'=0xfac7
                    time_waited: >= 2 sec (still in wait)
            [3 samples,                                          10:23:24 - 10:23:26]
                not in wait at each sample
            [13 samples,                                         10:23:11 - 10:23:23]
                idle wait at each sample
            [1 sample,                                                      10:23:10]
                not in wait at each sample
            [8 samples,                                          10:23:02 - 10:23:09]
                idle wait at each sample
            [2 samples,                                          10:23:00 - 10:23:01]
                not in wait at each sample
            [5 samples,                                          10:22:54 - 10:22:59]
                idle wait at each sample
            [2 samples,                                          10:22:52 - 10:22:53]
                not in wait at each sample
            [1 sample,                                                      10:22:51]
                idle wait at each sample
            [1 sample,                                                      10:22:50]
                not in wait at each sample
            [2 samples,                                          10:22:48 - 10:22:49]
                idle wait at each sample
            [2 samples,                                          10:22:46 - 10:22:47]
                not in wait at each sample
            [9 samples,                                          10:22:37 - 10:22:45]
                idle wait at each sample
            [2 samples,                                          10:22:35 - 10:22:36]
                not in wait at each sample
            [1 sample,                                                      10:22:34]
                idle wait at each sample
            [2 samples,                                          10:22:32 - 10:22:33]
                not in wait at each sample
            [1 sample,                                                      10:22:31]
                idle wait at each sample
            [1 sample,                                                      10:22:30]
                not in wait at each sample
            [1 sample,                                                      10:22:29]
                idle wait at each sample
            [2 samples,                                          10:22:27 - 10:22:28]
                not in wait at each sample
            [1 sample,                                                      10:22:26]
                idle wait at each sample
            [1 sample,                                                      10:22:25]
                waited for 'db file scattered read', seq_num: 9258
                    p1: 'file#'=0x6
                    p2: 'block#'=0x1fecd0
                    p3: 'blocks'=0x4
                    time_waited: 0.007933 sec (sample interval: 0 sec)
            [5 samples,                                          10:22:20 - 10:22:24]
                idle wait at each sample
            [4 samples,                                          10:22:16 - 10:22:19]
                not in wait at each sample
            [3 samples,                                          10:22:13 - 10:22:15]
                idle wait at each sample
            [2 samples,                                          10:22:11 - 10:22:12]
                not in wait at each sample
            [7 samples,                                          10:22:04 - 10:22:10]
                idle wait at each sample
            [6 samples,                                          10:21:58 - 10:22:03]
                not in wait at each sample
            [30 samples,                                         10:21:30 - 10:21:57]
                idle wait at each sample
        ---------------------------------------------------
        Sampled Session History Summary:
            longest_non_idle_wait: 'enq: TX - row lock contention'
            [3 samples, 10:23:27 - 10:23:29]
                    time_waited: >= 2 sec (still in wait)
```

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have had two session that each waited for a resource that was held by the other session.

For example:

**Session 1**

```
update table_ .... where x = 100;
```

Session 1 has now locked the record `x=100`. No other session can modify this record until Session1 either commits or rolls back (that is: ends the transaction).

**Session 2**

```
update table_ .... where x = 200;
```

Session 2 has now locked the record `x=200`.

Then, still session 2:

```
update table_ .... where x=100;
```

Since Session 1 has locked that record, this statement will wait until it can do the  modification (that is, until Session 1 end its transaction).

**Session 1**

```
update table_ .... where x=200;
```

Now, this is the deadlock. Since `x=200` is locked by Session 2, Session 1 cannot proceed until the transaction of Session 2 ends. But Session 2 cannot proceed because it is also waiting for Session 1.

Hence the Deadlock Error `ORA-00060`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rene for your reply.. Now I do understand what the problem is.. Just one question... Should not there be any Table level lock? First session should have blocked the whole table and should not let the other session access that table? This is what I expect as per my knowledge.. Could u please clarify that for me?

Comment: Your knowledge is wrong. When you modify a record, only the record is locked, not the entire table. Think about it, just a single update on a record would block all other sessions from doing updates on the table, that would be highly inefficient. *If* you want to lock the table, then explicetely use `lock table table_ in ... mode`, but I strongly discourage you from doing that.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rene for clarifying the same. I will look into the system architecture and try to find the root cause. Thanks again for ur help..